# помогите сделать такой переключатель ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

подскажите как сверстать такой переключатель ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @RaZik [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Answer (score 6):

То что вам надо это **горизонтальный ползунок** или **horizontal scroll** есть масса плагинов для их реализации.
Один из них я реализовал внизу.
А некоторым из этих плагинов дам вам ссылку

[JQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html)

[jQuery Slider](http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/)

```js
function collision($div1, $div2) {
//определяем переменные
      var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
      var w1 = 40;
      var r1 = x1 + w1;
      var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
      var w2 = 40;
      var r2 = x2 + w2;
        
      if (r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
      return true;
      
    }
    
// // вызываем slider 

$('#slider').slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 500,
 values: [ 75, 300 ],
 slide: function(event, ui) {
  
  $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0) .price-range-min').html('$' + ui.values[ 0 ]);
  $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1) .price-range-max').html('$' + ui.values[ 1 ]);
  $('.price-range-both').html('<i>$' + ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - </i>$' + ui.values[ 1 ] );
  
  //
  
    if ( ui.values[0] == ui.values[1] ) {
      $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('.price-range-both i').css('display', 'inline');
    }
        
        //
  
  if (collision($('.price-range-min'), $('.price-range-max')) == true) {
   $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '0'); 
   $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'block');  
  } else {
   $('.price-range-min, .price-range-max').css('opacity', '1'); 
   $('.price-range-both').css('display', 'none');  
  }
  
 }
});

$('.ui-slider-range').append('<span class="price-range-both value"><i>$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0 ) + ' - </i>' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');

$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').append('<span class="price-range-min value">$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 0 ) + '</span>');

$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)').append('<span class="price-range-max value">$' + $('#slider').slider('values', 1 ) + '</span>');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}

.value {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  
  /* optional */
  
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}

.price-range-both.value {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  top: 26px;
}

.price-range-both {
  display: none; 
}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
  border-radius:50% !important;
}
.ui-widget-header {
  background:orange !important;
}
.ui-widget-content {
  background:#e1e6ea !important;
}
.value i {
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: добрые люды зачем ставите минусы свои все же работает идеально...

Comment: Видимо, минусы за то что отвечаете без достаточного внимания к вопросу: рекомендуете плагины, хотя вопрос в том "как сверстать?" - не факт, что ТСа устроит готовое; И в вопросе нет тегов/упоминаний `jquery` (указан тег `javascript`), но код предлагаете с использованием этой библиотеки...