# Нужна помощь, не знаю как сделать такие полосы прокрутки

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Нужно чтоб они были динамические, т.е при сдвижении ползунка чтоб менялось значение и цвет ползунка, в общем все на скрине. P.S. хотелось бы сделать на чистом js[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мы тут только помогаем программный код подкорректировать... Дак какая помощь вам нужна?

Comment: тут уже такое делали мы раз 500 :(

Comment: @Diskyp Извините не знал, ну сделать на скрине, в общем сверстать как правильно и добавить логику

Comment: @Избытоксусликов скиньте пожалуйста ссылку на подобные вопросы, буду благодарен

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806132/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/806149#806149

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [помогите сделать такой переключатель ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806132/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Там на Jquery и с помощью сторонних плагинов, а я хочу на чистом js, jQuery не знаю и учить его сейчас смысла нет

Comment: я тут ползунка не вижу

Comment: @МартинИден ну так вы и js не знаете. Вы хоть что-то сделали? Вы хотя бы блоки сверстали или вы хотите чтобы за вас все сделали по картинке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На чистом **Javascript** нужные стили я думаю  сами сможете добавит

```js
"use strict";

var volumeSlider = document.getElementById('volume');

var sliders = [volumeSlider];

function Slider(slider) {
  this.slider = slider;
  slider.addEventListener('input', function() {
    this.updateSliderOutput();
    this.updateSliderLevel();
  }.bind(this), false);
  
  this.level = function() {
    var level = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-input');
    return level.value;
  }
  
  this.levelString = function() {
    return parseInt(this.level());
  }
  
  this.remaining = function() {
    return 99.5 - this.level();
  }
  
  this.remainingString = function() {
    return parseInt(this.remaining());
  }
  
  this.updateSliderOutput = function() {
    var output = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-output');
    var remaining = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-remaining');
    var thumb = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-thumb');
    output.value = this.levelString();
    output.style.left = this.levelString() + '%';
    thumb.style.left = this.levelString() + '%';
    if (remaining) { 
      remaining.style.width = this.remainingString() + '%';
    }
  }
  
  this.updateSlider = function(num) {
    var input = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-input');
    input.value = num;
  }
  
  this.updateSliderLevel =function() {
    var level = this.slider.querySelector('.slider-level');
    level.style.width = this.levelString() + '%';
  }
}

sliders.forEach(function(slider) {
  new Slider(slider);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 3rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.slider-output {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.slider-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  width: 105%;
  margin-left: -2.5%;
  height: 2rem;
  outline: none;
}
.slider-input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 8rem;
}
.slider-thumb,
.top-thumb,
.tail-thumb {
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.75rem;
  background-color: #be1450;
}
.slider-thumb {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
.top-thumb {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}
.tail-thumb {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -1rem;
}
.slider-track {
  height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.slider-level {
  height: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #be1450;
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='volume' class='slider'>
  <output class='slider-output'>50</output>
  <div class='slider-track'>
    <div class='slider-thumb'></div>
    <div class='slider-level'></div>
  </div>
  <input class='slider-input' type='range' value='50' min='0' max='100' />
</div>
```